# The notification is displayed, but clicking the notification cannot jump to the page

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-pendingintent

**Goal: click the button to jump out of the notification, the user can jump from the notification to another page.**

The notification is displayed but clicking the notification cannot jump to the page.

I think the `PendingIntent` is wrong.

How to fix it?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String CHANNEL_ID = "Coder";
    NotificationManager manager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID, "DemoCode", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            assert manager != null;
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
       
        Button btDefault,btCustom;
        btDefault = findViewById(R.id.button_DefaultNotification);
        btCustom = findViewById(R.id.button_CustomNotification);
        btDefault.setOnClickListener(onDefaultClick);
    }
    
    private final View.OnClickListener onDefaultClick = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           
            Intent nextIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, nextIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, CHANNEL_ID);

            builder.setContentTitle("Notification");
            builder.setContentText("You have a new message");
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_accessible_forward_24);
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.setAutoCancel(true);

            manager.notify(1, builder.build());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this works for you. As mentioned in [android api](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/navigation)

You should consider user's expected navigation experience. So for making the best navigation using `pendingIntent` with `Notification`, you should do as follow:

**1. First define your app's hierarchy inside `AndroidManifest.xml`:**

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    ... >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<!-- MainActivity is the parent for SecondActivity -->
<activity
    android:name=".SecondActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    ...
</activity>
```

Now you told android that when a notification clicked, `SecondActivity` would be the child of `MainActivity` when user is navigating up.

**2. Create `PendingIntent` using `TaskStackBuilder`:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(MainActivity.this)
     .addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent)
     .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
```

Then you can set the `PendingIntent` we created to the notification. And now if user touches the notification, android system will navigate him to `SecondActivity` while  holding `MainActivity` in back stack.